# Android: How do I add two buttons into the action bar

Tags: java, android, button, android-actionbar, about-box

I would like to add two buttons into the action bar, but in my case just one button appears. What is wrong with my code?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:myApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
      myApp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="@string/action_about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    myApp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/> 
</menu>
```

Comment: are you using support library in your project? what is the min sdk of your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this use `always` instead of `ifRoom`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
      myapp:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="@string/action_about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    myapp:showAsAction="always"/> 
</menu>
```

Read documentation

> You can also use "always" to declare that an item always appear as an
>   action button. However, you should not force an item to appear in the
>   action bar this way. Doing so can create layout problems on devices
>   with a narrow screen. It's best to instead use "ifRoom" to request
>   that an item appear in the action bar, but allow the system to move it
>   into the overflow when there's not enough room. However, it might be
>   necessary to use this value if the item includes an action view that
>   cannot be collapsed and must always be visible to provide access to a
>   critical feature.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: Is there anyway to control where the buttons appear? I've got both of them crammed in to the far right corner at present and would like to move one of them to the far left.

Comment: @Deco simplest way to do something like this, is to call `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` on your toolbar and listen option menu event for item id `android.R.id.home`